# CountVector raising ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Trying to perform train_test_split on my dataset for MultinomialNB
data in a format as shown in figure_1:

[figure_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Jrd.png)

where duration_label is the target and everything else are the the features

since some of the features are strings, I need to convert them into floats using CountVector for MultinomialNB to work

That is where I run into this problem

```
X = df_train.iloc[:,0:5]
y = df_train.duration_label

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
vectorizer.fit(X)
X = vectorizer.transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.8, random_state = 0)
```

which raised this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-37ab36fb46be> in <module>
----> 1 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.8, random_state = 0)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2125         raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))
   2126 
-> 2127     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
   2128 
   2129     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    290     """
    291     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 292     check_consistent_length(*result)
    293     return result
    294 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    253     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    254     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 255         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
    256                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    257 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5, 40000]
```

Am I not supposed to use CountVector at all?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `CountVectorizer` properly. The text transformers of `scikit-learn` generally expect a one-dimensional input. More specifically, a sequence of items that can be of type string or byte.

You are however passing a whole dataframe to `CountVectorizer`, which is causing some weird processing of your data. When you check your error message it says that the number of samples in `X` and `y` are inconsistent, with only 5 samples in `X` and 40000 in `y`.

What happend is that `CountVectorizer` has mistaken the column names of `X` as the raw documents to transform. That is why there are only 5 samples in X.

To fix this particular processing error, only pass the column that needs to be processed to `CountVectorizer`. Looking on your dataframe, that would be either steps or ingredients:

```
X = df_train['steps']

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
```

This is how it should be used.

---

**Note**

That being said, you will need some more preprocessing to use `CountVectorizer` because your data is not in the right format. You should think about merging the two text columns into one to process them together. Also, you should make sure the raw documents are of type string. At the moment, you have stored them in a list for each data point separately which will lead to a processing error.

Comment: So I have to vectorize each feature individually then hstack them?

Comment: You could do that. But I do not recommend this approach as you will likely increase the dimensionality of your data considerably and make the prediction task more difficult. As mentioned in the answer, I would suggest combining ingredients and steps into one column and vectorize them as one document (looks like these are recipes anyway). This would result in fewer dimensions as there is probably a great overlap in words found in each column. However, what is good or bad always depends on the particular case.